# Does this sentence sound natural and correct?

Tags: grammar

If you are wondering about what to do, I've got some ideas. Is it correct? Does it sound natural to you?

Comment: It sounds fine. I personally would omit the "about", but your version is perfectly clear.

Comment: Hi Lana, welcome to EL&U. Regrettably, I'm flagging this question for closure: proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Is there a better way to write this passage?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely remove "about", as the commenter suggested.  It's jarring.  Without it, your sentence sounds fine.

> If you are wondering what to do, I've got some ideas.

Additionally, you might change "I've got" which of course means "I have got". You could simplify it:

> If you are wondering what to do, I have some ideas.

This would be my preference.